# ASP.NET 4.8 write memory stream to browser error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssl, httpresponse

We have an ASP.NET 4.8 project using VB.NET. We recently encounter an error, when exporting a large amount of data to an Excel object by writing memory stream to response, there is a browser error
"ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". But when the data size is small, it exports just fine. I have searched Stack Overflow and yet to find a relevant topic.

The export code is:

```
Dim stream As New MemoryStream()

Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Using wb As XLWorkbook = CreateExcelSheet(sArr, sTitle, sSubTitle)
        wb.SaveAs(ms, True, True)
        
        Dim bytesInStream As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
        ms.Close()
        response.Clear()
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=" + strExportFileName + ".xlsx")
        response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream)
        response.End()
    End Using
End Using
```

The `CreateExcelSheet` function will create an Excel object, and the code will write it to a memory stream, and then it's written to response.

There is no server error, so it seems to me it's a client side problem. However by inspecting the debug tools I could not find any useful information.

[image]

It says "the site" sent an invalid response. And the error is "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". But again the problem does not exist when the data size is small.

Comment: Is this from an `.ashx` handler - or an `.aspx` `Page` response? I'm wondering if the call to `Response.End()` is messing with the underlying TCP+HTTP connection _while_ other code in the project writes to the response (e.g. a `.master` page that still renders _after_ your binary response - which shouldn't even be possible, but I've seen it happen in some gnarly legacy apps).

Comment: I recommend you try to reproduce the issue with TLS/SSL disabled and while using Wireshark, and look at the raw TCP conversation and see if there's any extra "junk" data being written to the response, either before or after your Excel content.

Comment: One last thing... are you using Office COM Automation (aka Office Interop)? If so, then you'll inevitably run into problems [because it isn't designed to be used in-proc in a headless environment like ASP.NET](https://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/never-never-never-do-office-interop-on-the-server).

Comment: @Dai If it was in an ashx handler, I think there would be an HttpContext involved instead of a plain Response, e.g., `context.Response.Write()`. I agree with the implication that an ashx handler would be the correct way to do it, and I wonder if it needs a Response.Flush() before the finality of a Response.End().

Comment: Hi @Dai we are using DocumentFormat.OpenXml + ClosedXML for creating the excel object. And the code is form an .aspx page response. I'll start with the removal of Response.End() call and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a flush, see if that helps.

eg:

```
    response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream)
    response.Flush()   <--- try adding this
    response.End()
```